# Networking - VLAN & Router Linux

Tags: linux, iptables, dhcp, nat, vlan

I have a setup with 1 Debian router + 1 Debian DHCP Server.

I need to create multiple VLAN on my DHCP server. From my DHCP server I have internet access.

I managed to create and set up my VLANs and ping from my VLAN to my DHCP server but can't ping my router neither google... What should I check to fix this ?

Here my config in GNS3 :
[topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1FLj.png)

I have already configured VLANs and trunks in Cisco switches

Here my VLAN interface file on my DHCP server :

```
auto ens32
iface ens32 inet static
       address 192.168.2.1
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 192.168.2.254 #Router LAN Interface
       broadcast 192.168.2.255

auto ens32.3
iface ens32.3 inet static
       address 192.168.3.1
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       network 192.168.3.0
       broadcast 192.168.3.255
```

Here my DHCP config :

```
subnet 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0{
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    range dynamic-bootp 192.168.3.10 192.168.3.253;
    option routers 192.168.3.254;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.3.255;
    }
```

Could it be a gateway problem ?
Because inside my VLANs I can ping but can't go out, I get "Host unreachable"...
By the way, the router is NATing with Iptables.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly post your router and switch configurations. In the meanwhile, you must make sure that:

1. Switches are configured with right VLANs
2. Switch ports correspond to VLAN ID that the endpoint (PC) belong to
3. Router is configured with Inter-VLAN routing capability, also known as "Router on a Stick"